# How print group footer at bottom of page with Digital-Metaphors Report Builder

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, reportbuilder

I'm using Digital-Metaphors Report Builder 14x in Delphi 2010.  By default, group footers begin printing immediately after the last detail row of data.  I would like the group footer to print at the bottom of the page so that a perforation on the paper will line up with the data that goes in the footer.  What is the easiest way to do that?  Thanks!!

Comment: you should ask this on the vendor's support staff. I really never heard about this report tool until now..

Answer (score 1):

The [rbWiki](http://www.digital-metaphors.com:8080/) is helpful, [here](http://www.digital-metaphors.com:8080/Design/Groups/How_To...Align_Group_Footer_to_Bottom) is what you are looking for.